# C Function to get file name and pass to Caesar cipher function in menu driven program

Tags: c, function

I'm a bit confused about how to write a function that gets a file name of a text file and passes the name to another function that uses the name to open the text file to read, and perform Caesar cipher encryption on. I have searched all over Stack Overflow and the internet and haven't found an answer to this specific question.

I'm not using command line arguments. I'm using this program function with a `scanf` to get the file name into a string variable. The function prototypes are in a header file.

I'm also not sure when to open the file. Am I supposed to open it in the file name function, the encryption function, or in `main` where the switch case for the menu is?

Another thing I'm not sure what to do with checking that the file name is correct in the file name function if the file hasn't been opened within the file name function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages now.  [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)  Please don't create a wall of text like that as a question.  It is intimidating to try and read that.  Break it into paragraphs.  (I just did that for you — now you need to show us what you've got in the way of code).  You can write the code to open the file in one function called from `main()` (it will handle error messages, etc too); you can write another function to read lines from the file; you can write another function to encrypt text.

Answer (score 0):

To get the filename just get a string in from the user

```
char* filename[50];
scanf("%s",filename);
FILE* file = fopen(filename,"r+");
```

You now have the file with something that you can work with.
using `fscanf` you can get information from the similar to using scanf

```
fscanf(file,"%s", code);
```

For the other stuff, that is something that's in the scope of your project, that you will need to figure out for yourself.

Comment: I've made a lot of progress on my program. Thanks for the help everyone. I still have an issue with two other functions. I'm having trouble figuring out this function where I'm trying to let the user view the file but only the first ten lines from the file.